# Reading back ATmega328p program using FTDI Basic

Tags: arduino, atmel, arduino-ide, avrdude

I am trying to read the application I programmed to an ATMega328p atmel processor using the FDTI Basic small usb board, I am using Avrdude 6.0.1 and I am using the following command:
avrdude.exe -p m328p -C avrdude.conf -c 2232HIO -U flash:r:outputTry.bin:r

And I am getting the following error:

> avrdude.exe: Error: no libftdi or libusb support. Install libftdi1/libusb-1.0 or libftdi/libusb and run configure/make again.
>
> avrdude.exe: programmer operation not supported

One of my main concerns is the type of programmer I should use if I am using this FDTI Basic.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install ftdi drivers from there:

- http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ZMO, but I solved the issue, I used arduino as programmer and my main issue was with the baud rate settings so I used this command:
avrdude.exe -p m328p -C avrdude.conf -c arduino -U flash:r:outputTry.bin:r -b 57600

So anyone who wants to use the FTDI basic (for sure after downloading the drivers) you can use the above command to read the flash back but you have to make sure of the baud rate you used when you uploaded the boot loader to your ATmega328.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your version of avrdude is not linked with libftdi and has to be compiled and linked with libftdi. You can do this by getting the source code and compiling it for your self.